# "Exception "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client version 8.1.7 "

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, system.data.oracleclient

I recently had to move to a new computer. I periodically run a powershell script at the terminal of Visual Studio Code and I wrote the script a year or two ago. I'm trying to re-setup to run the script on the new computer.

This is the code:

```
$con = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."
```

At the top of the script, I do this:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient

Also, I have added the extension Oracle Developer Tools for VSCode.

I don't see why I'm still getting this error.  I need this to run sql queries.

I googled the issue and saw [Oracle Client exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832208/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7-or-greate), but I think this should be working with what I have.