# how to resolve connection error while connecting to oracle database in visual studio 2008 for crystal report

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I want to create crystal report in visual studio 2008. I create a project and add a crystal report, then I go to database and click database expert. I choose OLEDB (ADO) and select Microsoft OLE DB provider for oracle. When I enter the service name, user ID and password I get a connection error ORA 12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
I checked the tnsnames.ora file and sqlnet.ora file. There were no syntax errors and TNSNAMES was present in sqlnet.ora file. need help to resolve this connection error.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206055/oracle-ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-service-name-error or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228739/vs2010-oracle-driver-ora-12154-tsncould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier first. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have done the following:Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.